# How can I make EventSource work with any Content-Type header?

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I have a server which sends data exactly in the format expected by the SSE client, but Chrome closes the connection immediately as it gets the Content-Type header with this message: `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Is it possible to make `EventSource` work even if the server doesn't set the appropriate `text/event-stream` content type?

Comment: Apparently, the answer is that it's not possible, so I ended up setting up an nginx proxy to deal with headers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, sorry. In fact a browser that did not would not be following [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#text-event-stream).

(I think the motivation for a new MIME type was that proxies could recognize it and treat it differently.)